# How to enable file management in Thunar

Tags: filemanager, archive, thunar

I think it it convenient that when a file manager opens a dialog I can right click on a file and for example expand an archive and then open a file in the archive, or edit the file with Gimp by rightclicking and opening it with gimp without having to close the file dialog. Why doesn't Xfce's Thunar do this?

[image: Thunar screenshot]

Comment: .... It does do this, though?

Comment: @TheBrownOne I wish I could. I updated the question so that you see what I see. If I want to unzip the archive I must exit the dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xfce - GUI for File Compression?](/q/326884/175814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The screenshot shows a Thunar dialog.  Thunar is one of the most versatile and customizable file managers on Linux.  If you want to add items in the context menu, use `Edit/Configure custom actions`.  There are several posts on doing this, all over the internet.  [Here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) is one of them.
2. Using an "Open" dialog is not the best way to have Thunar do what you want.  You should open Thunar itself and right-click on the desired file or folder and select the proper action.

Comment: Can it also do search? Gnome's file manager can do search. I like the Thunar interface but it couldn't do what I want, so this comment is written from Gnome. In fact no window manager works the way I want. I want a shortcut also that opens the file manager but I can't find such a shortcut.

Comment: Yes.  If you want Thunar to do search, you have to install a search program, like **gnome-search-tool** or **catfish**.  Then you have to create an action to use that program with the appropriate parameters.  For example: `gnome-search-tool --hidden --path=%f` will open the tool and search for the file you type, recursively inside the designated path, including hidden files.